# Hive Query failing with Heap Issue

Tags: java, cassandra, hive

Below is the hive query am running,

INSERT INTO TABLE temp.table_output

```
SELECT /*+ STREAMTABLE(tableB) */ c.column1 as client, a.column2 as testData, 
    CASE WHEN ca.updated_date IS NULL OR ca.updated_date = 'null' THEN null ELSE CONCAT(ca.updated_date, '+0000') END as update
    FROM temp.tableA as a 
    INNER JOIN default.tableB as ca ON a.column5=ca.column2
    INNER JOIN default.tableC as c ON ca.column3=c.column1 WHERE a.name='test';
```

TableB is having 2.4 billion rows (140 GB), TableA and TableC is having 200 million records around.

Cluster consists of 3 Cassandra data nodes and 3 Analytics node (Hive on top of cassandra), with 130GB ram on each node.

TableA, TableB, TableC are hive internal tables.

Hive cluster heap size is 12GB.

Can someone tell me when I run hive query, am having heap issue and it fails to complete the task?? Its the only job running on hive server.

Task fails with below error,

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Read failed from file: cfs://172.31.x.x/tmp/hive-root/hive_2015-03-17_00-27-25_132_17376615815827139-1/-mr-10002/000049_0
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraInputStream.read(CassandraInputStream.java:178)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.init(SequenceFile.java:1508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1486)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileRecordReader.<init>(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.getRecordReader(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.<init>(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:65)
    ... 16 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing get_remote_cfs_sblock
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.retrieveSubBlock(CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.java:537)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraSubBlockInputStream.subBlockSeekTo(CassandraSubBlockInputStream.java:145)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraSubBlockInputStream.read(CassandraSubBlockInputStream.java:95)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraInputStream.read(CassandraInputStream.java:159)
    ... 25 more

Caused by: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing get_remote_cfs_sblock
    at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Dse$Client.recv_get_remote_cfs_sblock(Dse.java:271)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Dse$Client.get_remote_cfs_sblock(Dse.java:254)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.datastax.bdp.util.CassandraProxyClient.invokeDseClient(CassandraProxyClient.java:655)
    at com.datastax.bdp.util.CassandraProxyClient.invoke(CassandraProxyClient.java:631)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.get_remote_cfs_sblock(Unknown Source)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.retrieveSubBlock(CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.java:515)
    ... 28 more
```

Hive.log

```
2015-03-17 23:10:39,576 ERROR exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - Examining task ID: task_201503171816_0036_r_000023 (and more) from job job_201503171816_0036
2015-03-17 23:10:39,579 ERROR exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - Examining task ID: task_201503171816_0036_r_000052 (and more) from job job_201503171816_0036
2015-03-17 23:10:39,582 ERROR exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - Examining task ID: task_201503171816_0036_m_000207 (and more) from job job_201503171816_0036
2015-03-17 23:10:39,585 ERROR exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - Examining task ID: task_201503171816_0036_r_000087 (and more) from job job_201503171816_0036
2015-03-17 23:10:39,588 ERROR exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - Examining task ID: task_201503171816_0036_m_000223 (and more) from job job_201503171816_0036
2015-03-17 23:10:39,591 ERROR exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - Examining task ID: task_201503171816_0036_m_000045 (and more) from job job_201503171816_0036
2015-03-17 23:10:39,594 ERROR exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - Examining task ID: task_201503171816_0036_m_000235 (and more) from job job_201503171816_0036
2015-03-17 23:10:39,597 ERROR exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - Examining task ID: task_201503171816_0036_m_002140 (and more) from job job_201503171816_0036
2015-03-17 23:10:39,761 ERROR exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - 
Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_201503171816_0036_m_000036

URL:
  http://sjvtncasl064.mcafee.int:50030/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201503171816_0036&tipid=task_201503171816_0036_m_000036
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: Java heap space

2015-03-17 23:10:39,777 ERROR ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the stack trace that indicates the heap issue. Can you please post/inspect the hive and hadoop logs?

Comment: I assumed, its a heap issue, because the ram on all 3 nodes were maxed out. Can you think of anything else from experience, what else could have caused it? This is not a production ready configuration of hive, so am open for configuration suggestions, if/which can fix this. Queries with million*million joins work fine. Issue starts with billion * million joins

Comment: RAM can be maxed out for unrelated reasons, there is nothing wrong with it being maxed out. Please try to fetch and inspect the HIVE and HADOOP logs on the nodes involved, especially on the failing node.

Comment: Added logs from hive.log. It seems indeed Heap issue. Am curious what shall be usual cluster heap size on such server(currently 12gb), or the forked jobs take heap size from somewhere else?

Comment: I gave some links in my answer, since it is easier that way. You will need to limit the number of map and reduce tasks based on the amount of JVM Heap memory you make available to them. You can increase Heap size, but you also need to play with the size of the New Generation Memory size to avoid nasty GC pauses. All of the hadoop settings explanations are in these links too.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, the hadoop errors on the tracker side are not very descriptive - like "there was a problem retrieving data from one of the nodes". In order to find out what had really happened, you need to get the system.log, both hive and hadoop task logs from each node, especially the one that did not return data back on time, and look at what the problem was there at the time of the error. In the Ops Center you can actually click on the hive job in progress and watch what is going on on each node, then see what was the error that caused your job interruption.

Here are some links that I found to be very useful. Some of these links are for older versions of DSE, but they still give a good start on how to optimize Hadoop operations and memory management.

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tuning-dse-hadoop-map-reduce

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaHivTune.html

https://support.datastax.com/entries/23459322-Tuning-memory-for-Hadoop-tasks

https://support.datastax.com/entries/23472546-Specifying-the-number-of-concurrent-tasks-per-node

You may also want to read [this article](http://tech.shift.com/post/74311817513/cassandra-tuning-the-jvm-for-read-heavy-workloads). Sometimes, timeouts may be due to major Garbage collections.

HTH